# Ellipsis with "would be"

Tags: sentence-construction

Having trouble with ellipsis.
I want to say that at one point in time, there was not a lot of songs that we would label "tango" today, but that the very fact that there was not a lot makes "the songs that we *would* label tango today" worth investigating.

Is any of the following sentences correct?

"There was not a profusion of songs that would be labeled 'tango' today - which obviously makes those highly worth investigating"

"There was not a profusion of songs that would be labeled 'tango' today - which obviously make those that *would* highly worth investigating"

"There was not a profusion of songs that would be labeled 'tango' today - which obviously makes those that *would be* highly worth investigating"

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The versions with "would" and "would be" are grammatical, but they aren't easy to read. It might be easier to make the reference with a word like "few":

There were few songs that we would label 'tango', and that makes those few worth investigating.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very clear answer. Your sentence is indeed easier to read but the context of my paragraph makes it difficult to skip my "there was not a profusion of". Would it be correct and slightly easier to read if I said "There was not a profusion of songs that would be labeled 'tango' today, and that makes the few that _would_ worth investigating"? Thanks.

Comment: That sentence works, but it's not as easy to read. "Profusion" is more often used in a positive sense. I think "There were not many" or "There were few" might work better.

Comment: OK. Great, thanks a lot for your clear advice! - Sorry, I can't upvote your answer, seems I haven't got enough points yet